# spelling change from verb form to noun form

Tags: orthography

Is there a reason why the verb is ABSORB but in the noun form the B becomes a P---ABSORPTION?

Comment: It's because the ancient Romans couldn't pronounce /bt/ in the middle of words, so *absorbtio* (derived from the verb [*absorbeo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absorbeo#Latin)) turned into *absorptio* in Latin. [See Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/absorption)

Comment: It's true that the Romans pronounced it that way, but so do we, and there's a good reason. /bt/ is a consonant cluster that starts out voiced /b/ and ends voiceless /t/. In English and Latin, as in many languages, consonant clusters are preferentially either all voiced or all voiceless, depending on which type is last. In /bt/, voiceless /t/ is last, so the voiced /b/ preceding it goes voiceless to agree with with /t/ in voicing value. The voiceless version of /b/ is /p/, so it turns out that this is the reason for the change -- it's a natural phonetic trait.

Answer (score 2):

**Latin;** it happens more with three-syllable words, and less common words.

The same thing happens when a **scribe** writes **scripture,** or chisels **inscriptions.**